# How to tell if linux process is 64bit

Tags: linux, 64-bit

Given the pid of a process that's running on a x64 linux, how do I tell if it's running a 32 or 64 bit binary?

I can look at the binary it's running out of 'ps' and do a file on that but I was wondering if there's a way to tell by looking at /proc/ or something like that.

Answer (score 33):

You can use `file` to get that information:

For example:

```
chris@obsidian:~$ file /usr/bin/perl
/usr/bin/perl: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

or read from /proc/

```
chris@obsidian:~$ file -L /proc/[PID]/exe
/proc/[PID]/exe: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), for GNU/Linux 2.6.8, dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

This will tell you if it is 64 or 32-bit.

Comment: Thank you to add a tip about `/proc`.  I didn't know that was possible before I read this answer... and I needed it today.  `:)`

Answer (score 9):

Starting from the `PID` you can:

```
file -L /proc/PID/exe
```